# Unique Character Count

Tags: perl

Hi I an extreme novice and I need help on what I should type so that the unique character count is displayed based on what the user inputs from their keyboard
I already have it set up to show the character count in the string

Here is the Code:

```
#!C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl
use strict;
use warnings;
print "Input Username";
my $str = <>;
chomp ($str);
print "You have typed: $str\n";
my $str_length = length($str);
print "Total Characters = " . $str_length . "\n";
exit;
```

Comment: Nice exercise. To what extent is this homework?

Comment: You may start with `my @chars = split //, $str;`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response its a very simple assignment I know but I just cant seem to figure out the unique count part But I believe what you have shown me is right here is the assignment

Comment: The program must store this string that the user enters in a scalar variable
(e.g., $arbitrary_string, $input_string, etc.).
• The program will then calculate two (2) items pertaining to the input string:
o total number of characters (including spaces & punctuation).
o number of unique characters (including spaces & punctuation).
• To solve one or both of the count calculations, the split function might be
useful in the following manner: my @chars = split(//, $arbitrary_string);

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function to get what you need:

```
sub func($) { my ($str, %hash) = shift; $hash{$_}++ for split //, $str; (length $str, scalar keys %hash) }
```

and this if you need to get count of certain char:

```
sub uniq_ch_count($$) { my ($ch, $str, %hash) = @_; $hash{$_}++ for split //, $str; $hash{$ch} }
```

EXAMPLE 1:

```
my ($chars_count, $uniq_chars_count) = func('one two three four');
print $chars_count . " " . $uniq_chars_count . "\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
18 10
```

EXAMPLE 2:

```
print uniq_ch_count('d', "asdjkasdjd sdfj d ") . " " . uniq_ch_count(' ', "asdjkasdjd sdfj d ") . "\n";
```

OUTPUT:

```
5
3
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method would be to use a hash:

```
# split the string into an array of characters
my @chars = split //, $str;  

# lists of values can be assigned to multiple indexes at once
# here we assign each character an empty value, but since hash 
# keys are unique in nature, every subsequent assignment overwrites
# the first.
my %uniq; 
@uniq{@chars} = ();          

# next get the list of keys from the hash and treat that list as 
# a scalar which gives you the count
my $count = scalar keys %uniq;
```

See: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices

Comment: Since this is a homework question, some additional explanation might be in order (especially the hash slice).

Comment: If it's homework, I'm feeling conflicted about giving him the answer in the first place. But explanation never hurts.

Comment: I appreciate the help the teacher told us to use the internet since that is our greatest resource when it comes to code and such

Comment: Someone telling you the answer doesn't help you understand what's going on. That's why traditionally we resist "homework" questions - because the point isn't to get to the answer, it's to understand what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so the magic keyword here - as far as Perl is concerned is 'unique'. Because that usually means a hash is the tool for the job.

In perl, a hash is a set of key-value pairs, which means it's great for counting numbers of unique items.

So if you take your string, and split it into characters:

```
my %count_of;
foreach my $character ( split ( '', $str ) ) {
    $count_of{$character}++;
}
```

You can then print out `%count_of`:

```
foreach my $character ( keys %count_of ) {
   print "$character = $count_of{$character}\n";
}
```

But because `keys %count_of` gives you an array containing each 'key' - one of the nice tricks in perl, is an array in a scalar context, is just a number representing the number of elements. So you can do:

```
print scalar keys %count_of, " unique characters in $str\n";
```